# Could not load type 'System.IO.Path' from assembly 'System.Runtime when deploying Azure function

Tags: c#, .net, azure, function

When deploying function to Azure unsing dotnet 6 I get the following error:

```
Could not load type 'System.IO.Path' from assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
```

In the startup script I use:

```
.AddJsonFile(System.IO.Path.Combine(context.ApplicationRootPath, "appsettings.json"), optional: true, reloadOnChange: false)
```

To get the path to the `appsettings.json`
Is there a way to avoid using `Path.Combine` (I'm testing on windows and deploying to linux) or alternatively is there a fix for this error?

Comment: `.SetBasePath(context.FunctionAppDirectory).AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")`

Comment: That did work although FunctionAppDirectory was not available and I went with ApplicationRootPath.

Not sure if related but now I'm getting a new error:

```Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.```

Comment: So the second Issue was not directly related (I was using a depricated package) and your solution solved the issue I was posting about. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In the below way I achieved the task of using appsettings.json variables:

```cs
ConfigurationBuilder
                    .SetBasePath(basePath)
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                    .AddEnvironmentVariables();
```

This is something which is similar to CodeCaster suggested, thanks to him :)